# Routes with optional parameters prevent other routes from loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I have 3 routes in my express based nodejs app.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 //
})

app.get('/findOne', function (req, res) {
 //
})

app.get('/getFour', function (req, res) {
 //
})
```

I have a query parameter "product" in the index route that is available as /?product=XXXX. And everything works fine and as intended.

Now I added the product as an optional variable to the index route

```
app.get('/:product?', function (req, res) {
 //
})
```

The index route is working but the other routes are throwing weird jquery error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Did you put the index route with optional parameter as the first route in the list??

Comment: It looks like `app.get(["/", "/:product?"], func......`

Comment: I mean, does it comes before the `/findOne` and `/getFour` routes??

Comment: Yes, It was the first in the routes.

Comment: Okay. I think that as it has an optional parameter, it'll be matched first preventing the following to work. You may try putting it after all specific routes.

Comment: I moved the parameterized route to the bottom and it worked. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add it as an answer and you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the index route with optional parameter as it's at the route list's top will be matched first preventing the following specific ones to get matched. So you have to put the specific routes first before adding the ones with optional parameter.